# Closing the Handle in desugared code

Tags: haskell

Does it matter if I don't close both handles but to be safe how would I do so in the desugared [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html) example

```
import System.IO
import Data.Char(toUpper)

main :: IO ()
main = do 
       inh <- openFile "input.txt" ReadMode
       outh <- openFile "output.txt" WriteMode
       mainloop inh outh
       hClose inh
       hClose outh

mainloop :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
mainloop inh outh = 
    do ineof <- hIsEOF inh
       if ineof
           then return ()
           else do inpStr <- hGetLine inh
                   hPutStrLn outh (map toUpper inpStr)
                   mainloop inh outh
```

to

```
capitalize = openFile "input.txt" ReadMode >>=
             \x -> hGetContents x >>=
             \y -> openFile "output2.txt" WriteMode >>=
             \z -> hPutStrLn z (fmap toUpper y)
```

Everything works except for "output2.txt" file which has a `^M` character at the end of each line.

Comment: The first sentence in your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only closing the handles in the happy path. You must use `withFile` or `bracket` instead so that the handles will be closed even when an exception is thrown.

For example:

```
capitalize = withFile "input.txt" ReadMode $
             \x -> hGetContents x >>=
             \y -> withFile "output2.txt" WriteMode $
             \z -> hPutStrLn z (fmap toUpper y)
```

Without `withFile`:

```
capitalize = openFile "input.txt" ReadMode >>=
             \x -> hGetContents x >>=
             \y -> openFile "output2.txt" WriteMode >>=
             \z -> hPutStrLn z (fmap toUpper y) >>
             hClose x >>
             hClose z
```

Comment: What's "happy path"? Any idea why I'm getting `^M` character at the end of every line?

Comment: The happy path is the path the code takes if no errors occur. `^M` probably has to do with Windows vs. Unix line endings, I don't know the exact cause.